# Oracle SQL deveoper

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence

I am required to make an automated time system. I wanted to know which SHIPPING1, SHIPPING have many truck, each truck will be at loading dock for 30 minutes, 
E.G. :

> SHIPPING 1 : 3 TRUCKS

```
truck    Time
-----    ----- 
truck1   11.00,
truck2   11.30.
truck3   12.00
```

If i entered time for truck 1, then truck 2 will allocated to 30 minute after that, etc.

Is it possible to make the auto sequence for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here you find something about [ask] and how to build a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using sequencer:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TRUCK_SEQUENCE MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 0 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

SELECT 'NEXT_CAR',
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('08.08.2016 10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+1/24/60*30*TRUCK_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
 FROM DUAL;
```

Cons: Once you pull from sequencer, that time frame is lost. This means, that if you for example decide, that you won't load car 3 at 11:00 (delete from table) but you want load car 4 (another insert), you get 11:30. It's actual feature of sequencer.

**Solution using max time from table:**

```
WITH LOAD_TIMES AS
  (SELECT 'TRUCK1'                                       AS CAR,
    TO_DATE('08.08.2016 10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIME
     FROM DUAL
  )
 SELECT 'TRUCK2',
  TO_CHAR(MAX(TIME)+1/24/60*30, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
   FROM LOAD_TIMES;
```

Cons: you query whole table every single time to find max used time and then increment it.

**Common for all solutions:**

```
--This is basic offset (date to start with)
TO_DATE('08.08.2016 10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Exactly, I've also stated in the cons section of this solution. Please note original request however **is it possible to make the auto sequence for this** ? If I wanted to make something like this, I would look and try to find gaps first (which are not occupied) and not smaller than current sysdate, but that's much more complicated than what's requested. The request is very vague.

Comment: Do we even know what an 'auto sequence' is? I certainly don't.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this at `insert` statement instead of having a `sequence`.

Considering `TO_DATE('08.08.2016 10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` is the initial time of `shipping1`

```
INSERT INTO table1
(shipping_number, truck_number, truck_time) 
VALUES ('shipping1', 'truck3', 
(SELECT count(truck_number) 
FROM table1
group by shipping
WHERE shipping_number='shipping1')*30/(24*60)+TO_DATE('08.08.2016 10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')));
```